# Diagnostic.Process enters an infinite loop

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf tool-kit to convert my webpage to PDF. The code is working fine and it is also creating the PDF perfectly but the code below

```
    Dim process = New Diagnostics.Process()
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    process.StartInfo.FileName = wkhtmltopdfLocation
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = htmlUrl + " " + pdfSaveLocation
    process.Start()
    process.WaitForExit(500)
```

enters a never ending loop. I have rechecked my code and this code does not belong to any loop and there is no unhandled loop in my code either. But this piece of code keeps creating a new process over and over again and does not stop till I stop debugging the project. I'd really like to know what am I doing wrong over here.

Thanks.

Comment: One thing to look at, would be whether the process itself is spawning more processes.

Comment: I was calling it in the page I wanted to convert to PDF, hence the recalling. I realized it a bit late. Thank you though. :)